# Fit button into input row

Tags: css, button, ionic2

[image: Ionic2 Form Control]

I like to have an input line below a map, including the button (see image). It a directive component. The HTML is:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

<form [formGroup]="searchMapForm" (ngSubmit)="search(searchMapForm.value)">
    <ion-item class="button">
        <div id="map"></div>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item class="input">
        <ion-select placeholder="Land" formControlName="country">
            <ion-option value="DE" checked="true">Deutschland</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="AT">Österreich</ion-option>
            <ion-option value="CH">Schweiz</ion-option> 
        </ion-select>
        <ion-input placeholder="Postleitzahl" type="text" class="map-search" formControlName="postalCode"></ion-input>
    </ion-item> 
    <ion-item class="button">
        <div ion-button outline round small color="secondary" (click)="search(searchMapForm.value)">Suchen  </div>
    </ion-item>
</form>
```

The CSS is (I didn't do anything there):

```
search-map {
  #map {
    height: 30vh;
  }
}
```

I tried to place the button directly in the  above, but then it just vanished.

How can I get the button up into the line with country and postal code?

Comment: Please add your css also.

Comment: From the code you provided, i think .input has a width of 100% or is given display:block;

Comment: You can try by placing everything inside an `ion-row` with three `ion-col` inside, one for the select, the second one for the input, and the third one for the button.

Comment: @sebaferreras That works! The colums don't find a nice default width (Country is not wide enough)

Comment: Great! I've posted an answer because it was too long for a comment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ion-row` and `ion-col` elements to decide where everything should be placed ([docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#grid)). So by creating a single row with three columns you should be able to place everything in the same line. You can then adjust the width of each column by using the `width` attribute:

```
<ion-grid>
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col width-10>This column will take 10% of space</ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-grid>
```

The possible values could be:

```
Explicit Column Percentage Attributes
width-10    10%
width-20    20%
width-25    25%
width-33    33.3333%
width-50    50%
width-67    66.6666%
width-75    75%
width-80    80%
width-90    90%
```

Comment: I still have a problem: The <ion-select> tag doesn't fill the full col space and so doesn't show the full country name, but ... now. Can I tell the col that it should adjust after the select size?

Comment: Hmm... I think that's not possible, but maybe you can set the width of the col that holds the select to be big enough (`width-50` for instance) and with css you can set the width of the select element to fill that width

Comment: I found a good solution: I put an ion-item with the first two elements into one col and the button within an ion-item also. Then it looks nice. Thx.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)